# JPA SubGraph to define fetchtype of an embedded property

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.1, embeddable

I have an entity *Ride* which embeds an embeddable "entity" *Route*. *Route* has a List property *towns* with ManyToMany relation, so it has fetchtype LAZY (and I don't want to use EAGER). So I want to define an NamedEntityGraph for the entity *Ride*, to load load a *Ride* object with a *Route* with instantied List of *towns*.
But when I deploy my war, I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute [route] is not of managed type

**Ride**

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Ride.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Ride m")})
@NamedEntityGraphs({
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "rideWithInstanciatedRoute",
        attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "route", subgraph = "routeWithTowns")
        },
        subgraphs = {
            @NamedSubgraph(
                    name = "routeWithTowns",
                    attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("towns")
                    }
            )
        }
    )
})
public class Ride implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Route route;

    // some getter and setter
}
```

**Route**

```
@Embeddable
public class Route implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Town> towns;

    // some getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at Hibernate's implementation of [org.hibernate.jpa.graph.internal.AttributeNodeImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/graph/internal/AttributeNodeImpl.java#L115) lead us to the conclusion that `@NamedAttributeNode` cannot be:

- simple types (Java primitives and their wrappers, strings, enums, temporals, ...)
- embeddables (annotated with `@Embedded`)
- element collections (annotated with `@ElementCollection`)

```java
if (attribute.getPersistentAttributeType() == Attribute.PersistentAttributeType.BASIC || 
    attribute.getPersistentAttributeType() == Attribute.PersistentAttributeType.EMBEDDED ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        String.format("Attribute [%s] is not of managed type", getAttributeName())
    );
}
```

I didn't find similar restriction in JPA 2.1 spec, therefore it may be Hibernate's shortcoming.

---

In your particular case the problem is that `@NamedEntityGraph` refers to the `Route` class which is an embeddable, thus its usage in the entity graph seems to be forbidden by Hibernate (unfortunately).

In order to make it work you would need to change your entity model a little. A few examples that come into my mind:

- define `Route` as entity
- remove `Route` and move its `towns` field into `Ride` entity (simplifies the entity  model)
- move `route` field from `Ride` into `Town` entity, add map of `routedTowns` map to `Ride` entity:

  ```java
   @Entity
   public class Ride implements Serializable {
       ...
       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rides")
       private Map<Route, Town> routedTowns;
       ...
   }

   @Entity
   public class Town implements Serializable {
       ...
       @ManyToMany
       private List<Ride> rides;
       @Embeddable
       private Route route;
       ...
   }
  ```

Of course the entity graph may require changes accordingly.